# Access VBA Import Text File Stops Halfway

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using Access 2013.  I'm trying to import a .txt file into Access.  The text file is 700MB (19MM records).  My code filters the data and assigns a group value ("Inode") to keep associated records together - so I'm only bringing in roughly 600K records.

Here is a snippet of the source text file (you can see each Inode data group is separated by a dashed line):

[image]

I would like the final result to look like this:

[image]

For some reason, the program STOPS halfway through, at the SAME RECORD (roughly 8MM record mark).  I can't locate what the issue is.  I don't think it's a size issue as I have plenty of space.  I've tried implementing error handling, but to no avail. The code simply bypasses it and the program ends (msgbox "done" appears). Opening the text file and reviewing the record where it stops does not help. There is nothing wrong/different about that record.  It simply stops and I am baffled.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub ImportTextFile()
On Error GoTo Err_LogError
Dim strFile As String, strLine As String
Dim lngFreeFile
Dim sInode_Num As String
Set db = CurrentDb()
DAO.DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 1000000  <--- not sure if this helps
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblImport")
strFile = "C:\Data\store_data.txt"

    lngFreeFile = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Input As #lngFreeFile
    Do Until EOF(lngFreeFile)
        Line Input #lngFreeFile, strLine

    If Left(LCase(Trim(strLine)), 9) = "inode_num" Then
        sInode_Num = Trim(strLine)
    End If    

    If InStr(LCase(strLine), "kmditemlastuseddate") > 0 Or _
       InStr(LCase(strLine), "kmditemusecount") > 0 Or _
       InStr(LCase(strLine), "kmditemuseddates") > 0 Or _
       InStr(LCase(strLine), "kmditemdateadded") > 0 Then

        rs.AddNew
        rs![Inode_Num] = sInode_Num
        rs![FieldValue] = Trim(strLine)
        rs.Update

        End If
    Loop

Exit_LogError:
    MsgBox "done."
    Close #lngFreeFile
    Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_LogError:
    strMsg = "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical, "LogError()"
    Resume Exit_LogError

End Sub
```

NOTE:  I used SSMS import wizard and was able to ingest the text file in its' entirety (19MM records) in just a few minutes.  But the key to this is getting that Inode grouping so I can keep the associated records together.  If there is a way to do that through the wizard i'd like to know.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: How many characters does your text file contain? `Open strFile For Input As #lngFreeFile` limits the file to 2^31 characters iirc, you might need to use WinAPI to be able to handle larger files

Comment: @Erik:  Thanks...hmmm..well, not sure.  But I would imagine a lot more than 2^31.  Not sure how to use WINAPI with Access VBA - I'll peruse this site.  Any links available?

Comment: Don't think there are links for accessing files with WinAPI using VBA, it's a niche subject. I have some code lying around from an attempt to do asynchronous file writes which you might be able to repurpose, but I think I'd better write a full answer after you verify this is the problem. You can keep a counter when reading, and I'm 99% sure you hit EOF after reading 2^31 characters. This [docs page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/declare-statement) describes declaring external DLLs, but these are C++ apis and mapping types can prove difficult

Comment: Oh, and please let me know if you're on 64-bit or 32-bit Access. Writing code to work with large files/objects is generally a lot easier if you have access to the `LongLong` data type.

Comment: @Erik:  I think I found the solution..working from your observation regarding "open strFile for Input" limitations.  I found some code that uses CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").  Then with "obj.Readline" I can read each line separately.  Odd, I tried this method initially, but ran into error messages, primarily Error 62 "Input past end of file" and also 3035 "System Resource Exceeded".  But this go-around worked.

Comment: @Erik:  I'm using 64-bit Access, BTW.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was limited too, but might be wrong on that count. Feel free to write up your own answer, my attempt would be _way_ more complicated.

Comment: Please share your solution as an answer, not an edit to the question

Comment: @Erik:  Apologies, rather new to this.  Not sure how to do that.  My comment above explains the solution.  Is there a protocol I can follow?  Thanks.  Appreciate your timely response to all this.

Comment: Just take the code you edited in the top plus that comment, go to the bottom of the page, throw it in the answer box, and press _post your answer_. You'll get a little warning about answering your own question, that's all okay since you're really writing an answer, and done. Preferably, you come back in two days and press the green checkmark next to your answer to accept it and indicate it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution..working from Erik's observation regarding "open strFile for Input" limitations. I found some code that uses CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). Then with "obj.Readline" I can read each line separately, as opposed to reading the entire 19MM records into one recordset.

The new code is here:

```
Public Function ReadTextFile()
    On Error GoTo Err_LogError

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objTextStream As Object
    Dim strTextLine As String
    Dim strInputFileName As String
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblImport")
    strInputFileName = "C:\Data\store_data.txt"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFileName)

    Do While Not (objTextStream.AtEndOfStream)
        strTextLine = objTextStream.ReadLine

            If Left(LCase(Trim(strTextLine)), 9) = "inode_num" Then
                sInode_Num = Trim(strTextLine)
            End If
            '
            If InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "kmditemlastuseddate") > 0 Or _
               InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "kmditemusecount") > 0 Or _
               InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "kmditemuseddates") > 0 Or _
               InStr(LCase(strTextLine), "kmditemdateadded") > 0 Then
            '
            rs.AddNew
            rs![Inode_Num] = sInode_Num
            rs![FieldValue] = Trim(strTextLine)
            rs.Update

            End If

    Loop

    Exit_LogError:
        objTextStream.Close
        Set objFSO = Nothing
        Set objTextStream = Nothing
        MsgBox "done."
        Exit Function

    Err_LogError:
        strMsg = "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical, "LogError()"
        Resume Exit_LogError

    End Function
```